# On Linux where should I store non-subversion files for a web site?

Tags: linux, file-management

I've finally upgraded to a VPS. I'm planning to run about 4 - 6 sites off it each with a fairly sizable files directory. That is, user uploaded media content such as images and video clips.

I usually have a sites' files directory separate from the site itself connected by a symlink. I do this to make it easier to check sites into subversion as I do not want these kinds of files in my repositories.

On a Linux server where would be the best place to store these files?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple possibilities. First of all, you probably have an account other than root on those machines, which you use for your maintenance work. So one place could be that users home directory (say, `/home/maintuser`).

If you want to have those files stored separately from any user account, the place to locate them under is either `/usr/local` (the "local" indicates it is not maintained by the system; this is also where one should install manually-compiled software, as opposed to those software being installed via the systems packaging system -- i.e. `.tar.gz` opposed to `.deb`, `.rpm` etc).

A third common place is just below `/opt`, which originally was used for 3rd party "unfree" installations.